# Turning jquery into an includable, callable function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm so frustrated! As an ok PHP developer I can't get my head around the simplist of jquery problems!

I have recently moved my HTML jquery include to the end of the HTML body, instead of in the head to improve google pagespeed score.

This has broken some jquery which is used for simple comment voting. This was written badly as it repeats for every comment.

```
<div id="voterow-19907" class="commentfooter">UP</a> | <a id="comment-vote-down-19907" href="#" rel="nofollow">DOWN</a></div>


    <script>
    $("#comment-vote-up-19907").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/ajax.php",
            data: "a=rv&v=19907&d=up",
            success: function(data){
                $("#voterow-19907").text("Thank you for your vote")
            }
        });
        return false;                 
    });

    $("#comment-vote-down-19907").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/ajax.php",
            data: "a=rv&v=19907&d=down",
            success: function(data){
                $("#voterow-19907").text("Thank you for your vote")
            }
        });
        return false;                 
    });
    </script>
```

Since moving the jquery include to the bottom of the page this naturally doesn't work.

What I'm trying to do is turn the above code into a mini function I can include after the jquery include, then pass the ID and VOTE-DIRECTION to the function from the HTML a hrefs using the jquery DATA- attribute.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm running out of hair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, repeated codes will hurt your page than placement of JQuery file.

You can solve this problem using more general event listener. Remove all listeners inside code ***(all of them)*** and append the code below after Jquery include.

```
$('[id^=comment-vote]').click(function() {
    var elementId = $(this).attr('id');
    var elementIdParts = elementId.split("-");
    var voteType = elementIdParts[2]; 
    var id = elementIdParts[3]; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ajax.php",
        data: "a=rv&v="+id+"&d="+voteType,
        success: function(data){
            $("#voterow-"+id).text("Thank you for your vote")
        }
    });
    return false;                 
});
```

`$('[id^=comment-vote]")` selects all elements which have id starting with "comment-vote". If user clicks one of these elements, event handler gets id of elements, split into parts like "comment", "vote", "up", "19900". 2nd part is voteType and 3rd part is ID of row. We can use these variables while generating/operating AJAX request.

*I didn't try the code but the idea behind that would be beneficial for you.*

Comment: That's a really nice solution, and I actually understand it thanks to your comments, thank you!

Comment: However, it sadly doesn't work. It's still not binding properly

Comment: I've just noticed the quote miss matches in the opening, ' and ".

Comment: I corrected the quote typo, glad to hear you solved problem.

Answer (score 1):

To really give a great working answer, I would need to see your an example page / the exact structure of your html, but here's what I have for you.

In a script file that you include after jQuery, you can include something similar to the below code assuming your html is as follows:

```
<div id="voterow-1" class="voterow">
    <p class="voteresult"></p>
    <a class="upvote" href="#" rel="nofollow">UP</a>
    <a class="downvote" href="#" rel="nofollow">DOWN</a>
</div>
<div id="voterow-2" class="voterow">
    <p class="voteresult"></p>
    <a class="upvote" href="#" rel="nofollow">UP</a>
    <a class="downvote" href="#" rel="nofollow">DOWN</a>
</div>
```

Having the class of upvote and downvote makes it easy to target these elements in jQuery:

```
// After jQuery is loaded, the function passed to ready() will be called
$(document).ready(function () {
    // bind a click event to every direct child with the upvote class of an element with the voterow class
    $('.voterow > .upvote').click(function (event) {
        // get the voterow parent element
        var $parent = $(event.target).parent();
        // use regex to strip the id number from the id attribute of the parent
        var id = parseInt($parent.attr('id').match(/^voterow-(\d+)/)[1]);
        // call your ajax function
        vote(id, 'up', $parent.find('.voteresult');
    });

    $('.voterow > .downvote').click(function (event) {
        var $parent = $(event.target).parent();
        var id = parseInt($parent.attr('id').match(/^voterow-(\d+)/)[1]);
        vote(id, 'down', $parent.find('.voteresult');
    });

    function vote(id, direction, $resultElement) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/ajax.php",
            // here we have the id and the direction needed to make the ajax call
            data: "a=rv&v=" + id + "&d=" + direction,
            success: function(data){
                $resultElement.text("Thank you for your vote")
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is a demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/ECL376hZ3NOz8pBVpBMW?p=preview

Comment: Thank you Robert. The first comment actually answered the question in a really graceful way, but your example has certainly helped further my understanding of jquery

Comment: @Jon, glad I could help.